# Configuring multiple upload repositories in Gradle build

Tags: repository, release, gradle

I want to upload my artifacts to a remote Nexus repo. Therefore I have configured a snaphot and a release repo in Nexus. Deployment to both works.

Now I want to configure my build so I can decide in which repo I want to deploy:

- `gradle uploadArchives` should deploy to my snapshots repo
- `gradle release uploadArchives` should deploy to my release repo

This was my try:

```groovy
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven'

group = 'testgroup'
version = '2.0.0'
def release = false

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

dependencies{ providedCompile 'javax:javaee-api:6.0' }

task release <<{
    release = true;
    println 'releasing!'
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {

        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://.../nexus/content/repositories/releases"){
                authentication(userName: "admin", password: "admin123")
            }
            addFilter('lala'){ x, y -> release }
        }
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: "http://.../nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"){
                authentication(userName: "admin", password: "admin123")
            }
            addFilter('lala'){ x, y ->!release}
            pom.version = version + '-SNAPSHOT'
        }
    }
}
```

The build works if I comment out one of the two mavenDeployer configs, but not as a whole.
Any ideas how to configure two target archives in one build file?

Answer (score 5):

One solution is to add an `if-else` statement that adds exactly one of the two deployers depending on the circumstances. For example:

```groovy
// should defer decision until end of configuration phase
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                if (version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) { ... } else { ... }
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

If you do need to vary the configuration based on whether some task is "present", you can either make an eager decision based on [`gradle.startParameter.taskNames`](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/StartParameter.html#getTaskNames%28%29) (but then you'll only catch tasks that are specified as part of the Gradle invocation), or use the [`gradle.taskGraph.whenReady`](http://gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html#whenReady%28groovy.lang.Closure%29) callback (instead of `gradle.projectsEvaluated`) and check whether the task is scheduled for execution.

Comment: I guess i found a better solution (correct me if i'm wrong): Just adding another configuration (e.g. releaseArchives). Then I can add two repos, one for uploadArchives (snapshots) and one for uploadReleaseArchives (just releases). Another advantage is, that i don't have to change the project version when releasing. Maybe you can tell me whether my solution is bad, then i will accept your answer, or my solution is good/better , then i will answer my question and accept my answer. Since I'm new to Stackoverflow, I don't know if accepting own answers is bad practice....

Comment: Adding another configuration should work too, as long as you configure it to contain the same artifacts. In any case, you'll have to use a snapshot version for the snapshot artifact. Otherwise, clients won't recognize it as such.

Comment: @huzi Could you please post your own answer, not having to change the version code would be much better

Answer (score 5):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but shouldn't you use the separate snapshotRepository in this case (as opposed to an if statement)? For example,

```groovy
mavenDeployer {

  repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
    authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername, password: sonatypePassword)
  }

  snapshotRepository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/") {
    authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername, password: sonatypePassword)
  }
}
```

Comment: When/how does mavenDeployer know to use a snapshot vs release?