# uploadArchives with mavenDeployer to multiple repos

Tags: gradle

I have a gradle project that acts like a common library for two other projects.

The other two projects each hosts an embedded maven repository that I want the common project to deploy to.

I've tried this:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repositories {
                repository(url: '../../../project-web-service/repo')
                repository(url: '../../../project-app/repo')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this only deploys to the second repo.

I have read [Configuring multiple upload repositories in Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772154/configuring-multiple-upload-repositories-in-gradle-build), but it doesn't cover the mavenDeployer, so I'm kind of stuck right now.

Comment: You need to declare another `Upload` task.

Comment: Or maybe upload to a temporary repo and then copy to the other repo locations? How would I configure that? (new to gradle as you might have guessed)

Comment: Declaring another `Upload` task is the better approach. (The whole "embedded Maven repository" approach sounds smelly to me, but that's a different topic.)

Comment: And how would I go about doing that?

Comment: See `Upload` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can create two your own tasks (extends from `Upload`), just like this:

```
task uploadFirst(type: Upload) {
  uploadDescriptor = true
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repositories {
        repository(url: '../../../project-web-service/repo')
      }
    }
  }
}

task uploadSecond(type: Upload) {
  uploadDescriptor = true
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
      repositories {
        repository(url: '../../../project-app/repo')
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and was just able to solve it by giving the additional repositories names, but still leaving their own mavenDeployer closure.

For your example:

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            name = 'WebService'
            repository(url: '../../../project-web-service/repo')
        }
        mavenDeployer {
            name = 'App'
            repository(url: '../../../project-app/repo')
        }
    }
}
```