# how to flip between local and remote repo in gradle with old maven plugin?

Tags: maven, gradle

I am not using the new maven-publish plugin which looks awesome and would work perfectly for this use case because I keep reading how no one can get the signing of the jars to work (though I am open to an answer that explains that as well as I haven't found a blog on that saying it would work at this point).

Soooo, I would like easily to switch between publishing locally for testing and remotely.  My current build.gradle file is

https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/build.gradle

which has a commented out local repo and I keep flipping commenting on and off and would rather like to avoid that.  ie. these repos...

```
       //repository(url: "file://localhost/tmp/myRepo/")
        repository(url: "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/") {
          authentication(userName: sonatypeUsername, password: sonatypePassword)
        }
```

I read a post on doing something here but this failed with cryptic closure errors...

[Configuring multiple upload repositories in Gradle build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14772154/configuring-multiple-upload-repositories-in-gradle-build)

I put that in my subprojects section but that didn't work at all.  Ideally, using the graph whenReady sounds the best as it would be cool to only use remote repo if I am doing the release target.  I can't seem to get any of this to work though.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I was wrong, the below is only half working right now as when I ./gradlew jar, then I get this error... (so some targets work and others not...ouch)

```
Cannot cast object 'task ':uploadArchives'' with class 'org.gradle.api.DefaultTask_Decorated' to class 'org.gradle.api.tasks.Upload'
```

I did figure out a work around though it seems weird as targets in running tasks list are hidden now depending on if a variable is set which seems a little odd.  I would think there is probably a better way of doing this so all tasks are still listed, but for now my build file works by just doing a

```
if(project.hasProperty('projVersion')) {
  //task I want to be able to run
} else {
  //other task I want to run when no projVersion
}
```

so it works...the tasks are just invisible now until I do ./gradlew -PprojVersion=X to view them.